# How to position list in the center using flexbox?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, centering

I have 3 boxes that are stacked vertically using flexbox. They are positioned to the left now. I want to center them in horizontal direction. I tried div {margin:10px auto} and it works but css looks awkward. Is there any more elegant solution using special flexbox properties?

I want divs in center.

```css
section {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: teal;
}

div {
  background-color: silver;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 10px;
  line-height: 75px;
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<section>
 <div>apple</div>
 <div>banana</div>
 <div>pear</div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can center the divs using `align-items: center` and center the text inside the divs using `text-align: center` like this:

```css
section {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: teal;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
}

div {
  background-color: silver;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 10px;
  line-height: 75px;
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<section>
 <div>apple</div>
 <div>banana</div>
 <div>pear</div>
</section>
```

Comment: Excellent. That is what i was looking for. align-items works great

Answer (score 2):

You could use   `align-items: center;`

```css
section {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: teal;
  align-items: center;
}

div {
  background-color: silver;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 10px;
  line-height: 75px;
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<section>
 <div>apple</div>
 <div>banana</div>
 <div>pear</div>
</section>
```